# Test a component which is using a condition

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have this component that display fetched data from an API.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Fetch = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setState(data)
            });
    }, []);

    const render = () => {
        if (state.length) {
            return state.map(i => <p key={i.title}>{i.title}</p>)
        } else {
            return <p>Loading...</p>
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>List</h1>
            {
                render()
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default Fetch;
```

How you can see I have to test these 2 states:

```js
 const render = () => {
       if (state.length) {
           return state.map(i => <p key={i.title}>{i.title}</p>)
       } else {
           return <p>Loading...</p>
       }
 };
```

My test:

```js
describe('if all is ok', () => {
    test('if the async works', async () => {
        global.fetch = jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve({
            json:()=> Promise.resolve([{
                body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil si nulla",
                id: 2,
                title: "qui est esse",
                userId: 1
            }]),
            status: 200
        }));

        await act(async () =>render(<Fetch/>));
        expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('qui est esse')).toBeInTheDocument();

    })
});
```

Starting this test I get:

```js
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Loading.... This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>
        List
      </h1>
      <p>
        qui est esse
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How I see, the `Loading...` text does not appear, the test render just the `qui est esse`.

How to test these 2 states?

Comment: May be this will help https://medium.com/rd-shipit/testing-asynchronous-code-with-jest-and-testing-library-react-cfc185d7bd78

Answer (score 0):

To test two different scenarios, you need two different unit tests.

Your first test follows the scenario where your request resolves into an array containing at least an element, and triggers the if statement, since the conditions are met (state.length > 0).

Your second test should resolve a different response, such as an empty array, so that your `state.length` is falsy (empty), to trigger the else statement.